# Bash script for file transfer from one directory to another directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Would you be able share a bash script which moves file from one location to another location.
It should move one by one instead of copying all in one go.

Also it should not move same file again to avoid the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through each file in directory and issue a `mv` command to another directory like this:

```
for file in directory1/*; do mv -iv "$file" directory2; done
```